# Probability space convergence proof check

Tags: probability, measure-theory, solution-verification

Let $X_1,......,X_n...:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be independent random variables.

Suppose $\mathbb{P}(X_n=1)=p_n$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_n=0)=1-p_n$. TFAE

1. $X_n\rightarrow 0$ almost surely.
2. $\sum_np_n <\infty$

My attempt:

$(1)\implies (2)$.

We have by assumption $\mathbb{P}(X_n\not\to0)=0$.

**Shall we assume in this case that each $X_n$ only take the values 1 and 0?, why or why not?   if yes, then**:

$\mathbb{P}(X_n\not\to0)=0$. Hence $\mathbb{P}(X_n\rightarrow 0)=1$.

Suppose $\sum_np_n=\infty$. Then by Borel Cantelli, $\mathbb{P}(lim_nsup \{X_m=1\})=1$. Thus
$\mathbb{P}(\bigcup_n \bigcap_{m\geq n} \{X_n=0\})=0$. Now note

$\{$ $X_n\rightarrow 0\}$ $\subseteq$ $\bigcup_n \bigcap_{m\geq n} \{X_n=0\}$. Thus by monotonicity, $\mathbb{P}(X_n\rightarrow 0)=0$, contradiction.

$(2)\implies (1)$

If $\sum_n p_n<\infty$ then $\mathbb{P}(lim_nsup \{X_n=1\})=0$. Now note that

$\bigcup_n\bigcap_{m\geq n} \{X_n=0\}\subseteq \{$ $lim_nX_n\rightarrow 0\}$

Hence $\mathbb{P}(X_n\rightarrow 0)$=1

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. Your proof looks correct.

Comment: @WhoKnowsWho could you answer my question in bold, please?

Comment: Well, the way your $X_n$ are defined, it is clear that it takes only $0$ or $1$ value. So you don't actually assume that, but you know that. However, there is another thing I should point out in the proof of $1\implies 2,$ how do you get $P(X_n\not\to 0)=0$? If you make that as your assumption, you are actually proving $2\implies 1.$

Comment: @WhoKnowsWho thats what $X_n\rightarrow 0$ almost surely means